# $f$ holomorphic on $D(0,2R)$ with zeros $z_1,...,z_n$ in $D(0,R)$. Prove $|f(0)|\le \frac{\sup_{|z|\le R}|f(z)|}{R^n}|z_1...z_n|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $R>0$ and $f:D(0,2R)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a holomorphic function. Suppose $f$ has $n$ zeros $z_1,...,z_n$ in the closed disk $\overline{D}(0,R)$. I'm asked to prove that $|f(0)|\le \frac{M}{R^n}|z_1...z_n|$ where $M=\sup_{|z|\le R}|f(z)|$.
I managed to prove this for $n=1$ by applying Schwarz lemma but I couldn't do an induction.
I also managed to prove this if instead we had $M=\sup_{|z|<2R}|f(z)|$ by considering the function $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_1)...(z-z_n)}$ which is holomorphic on $D(0,2R)$. If $R<\delta<2R$ and $C(t)=\delta e^{it}\ \forall 0\le t\le 2\pi$ then by Cauchy's formula we have :
$g(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{g(\xi)}{\xi}d\xi$ so $|g(0)|\le \frac{M}{(\delta-R)^n}\iff |f(0)|\le \frac{M}{(\delta-R)^n}|z_1...z_n|$ and the result follows by letting $\delta\rightarrow 2R.$
I don't how to do answer this question with $M=\sup_{|z|\le R}|f(z)|$ though.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By considering the change of variable $w=z/R$ we reduce the problem to $R=1$ and the claim:

$|f(0)|\le \sup_{|z|\le 1|}|f(z)||z_1…z_n|$ where $f$ is holomorphic on a neighborhood of the closed unit disc and $z_k$ are its zeroes in the closed unit disc (the $2R$ is not that relevant, only that $f$ is holomorphic beyond $R$ and that actually can be replaced with weaker assumptions like continuity at the boundary)

Assume $0<|z_k|<1$ as if one $z_k=0$ the result is trivial ($f(0)=0$) and we can ignore the $|z_k|=1$ since RHS doesn't change; also we can assume that at least one such $0<|z_k|<1$ exists as maximum modulus applies otherwise.

Let $B(z)=\Pi_{k=1}^n\frac{z-z_k}{1-\bar z_k z}$ the Blaschke product with zeroes the same as $f$ in the open unit disc (remembering that now we assume $|z_k|<1$).

By maximum modulus $g=f/B$ which is analytic in the closed unit disc, satisfies $|f(0)|/|B(0)|=|g(0)| \le \sup_{|z|\le 1|}|g(z)|=\sup_{|z|\le 1|}|f(z)|$ since $|B(z)|=1, |z|=1$

But this is exactly what we need since $|B(0)|=|z_1..z_n|$ so we are done!